# Recalculate <option> based on selected option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select numbered from 1 to whatever is max. I want to remove the selected option and recalculate so the values of the new options don't exceed the selected option.

For example, if the max value is 3, then the options will be:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
```

Then if 1 is selected, the options will be:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
```

If 2 is selected, the remaining options will be:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
```

If 3 is selected then there will be no more options to select.

I can't get my brain wrapped aroun how to do the calculation.

A "live" example:

The options are equal to a number of carts. If the max value of carts is 3, then it would be like this:

If 1 cart is selected, then there is an option to reserve 1 or 2 carts. If 2 carts are selected, then there is an option to select 1 cart. If 3 carts are selected, then there a no more carts to select.

Comment: I would not do that, it's not user friendly to not be able to see selected option

Comment: Loop over the options that are left, and set value and text content to the loop counter/ index plus one.

Comment: It seems that either your description doesn't make much sense or I am not clever enough. Question: You want to _remove the selected option_ and modify the other option's values _to be below the selected (and removed) option's value_, right? If so, why should selecting "1" leave options "1" & "2" _intact_? And why should the selection of "3" _remove_ "1" & "2", since both are _below_ "3"?

Comment: Ok, a little more info:

The options = carts: There are 3 carts in total. 

If 3 carts are selected, then no carts are available. 

If 1 cart is selected, the 2 carts are available, and you can choose to reserve 1 or 2 carts. 

If there are 3 carts and you reserve 2 carts, then there is 1 cart is left to reserve.

Does it make sense now?

Comment: I've edited my question to describe what the select should do.

Comment: Consider using two selects/listboxes as seen [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/listbox/examples/listbox-rearrangeable/) for a better UX experience

Comment: *Does it make sense now?* - no.

Comment: "*I want to remove the selected option and recalculate so the values of the new options don't exceed the selected option.*" is the opposite of your example and your edit clarification.   If you remove "1" then "the values of "1+2" (from the example) clearly exceed "1".   Equally, if you *remove* "1" then why is "1" still in the list?  It's not been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger an event, when you click on an option on the list, to execute a function.
This function will get the maximum number of cards that can you play and calculate the difference between it and the number of cards selected.
After that, it will remove the number of cards that can't be played anymore.

Can you try this code below:

```js
/**
* Allows you to calculate the difference between the number of possible cards to play and the number of cards you have selected.
* And remove the number of cards that you can no longer play.
* 
* @param maxCard The max maximum numbers of cards that you can play
* @param selectedCard The number of cards that you selected to play
* @returns
*/
function calculateCard(maxCard, selectedCard) {
    let cardToShow = (maxCard - selectedCard);
    
    $(".card").each(function(index) {
        if($(this).val() > cardToShow)
            $(this).remove();
    });
}

/**
* Allows you to collect the maximum number of cards you can play
* 
* @returns max number of cards
*/
function getMaxCard(){
    let max = 0;
    $(".card").each(function( index ) {
        let element = $(this).val();
        if(element > max)
            max = element;
    });
    
    return max;
}

$(".card").on("click", function() {
    let maxCard = getMaxCard();
    let selectedCard = $(this).val();
    calculateCard(maxCard, selectedCard);
} );
```

```css
.card {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<option class="card" value="1">1</option>
<option class="card" value="2">2</option>
<option class="card" value="3">3</option>
<option class="card" value="4">4</option>
<option class="card" value="5">5</option>
```

Comment: I added more details to the solution.

Comment: Thanks mate. It did the trick!